# Access relative path in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to access the folder which is passed as a command line argument, however the path passed is relative. I need to read specific files from the folder location passed, but not sure how to do it.

The command line argument is ./folder

Tried abspath but still no result

```
PATH_TO_DATA_DIR = sys.argv[4]
my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(my_path, PATH_TO_DATA_DIR)
imageFile = ('%s\\file'%(path))
```

Comment: Resolving relative path is not your job. Underlying OS will handle it for you. Just simply use it directly is sufficient. e.g. open("./file.txt") works totally fine. If you expect a directory, use open(os.path.join(arg, "SomeSpecificFile.txt")).

Comment: It doesnot work. It is failing to locate the folder

Comment: I cannot reproduce such behavior. Please make sure the file you are looking for actually exists, and ensure your working directory is at the correct location.